# What is this mount with notched tab on a Soligor lens?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses, soligor

I bought a Soligor 80-200mm lens. The seller told me that it is M42 mount, but when I received it, I found out that is not M42. The seller doesn't answer my phone calls. I tried to recognize it alone.  I thought it might be MC/MD, so I bought an adapter and tried it on old Minolta cameras. Unfortunately, I was wrong. Can anyone help me find out what mount is this?

[image: soligor lens mount]

Answer (score 4):

The mount on your lens appears to be the one used by the [Rolleiflex SL35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolleiflex_SL35) line of cameras. Rollei couldn't be bothered to give the mount an official name, so it's unofficially known as the **Quick Bayonet Mount (QBM)**.

The mount locks using a notched tab (A) when turned clockwise. Other mounts that lock using a notched tab include Minolta SR/MC/MD and Contax/Yashica (C/Y). The easiest way to differentiate them is to note the types and positions of other lens-camera linkages.

For QBM, auto aperture is controlled by a pin (B) that's adjacent to the notched tab. Aperture setting for TTL metering is communicated to the camera via a tab (C) opposite the notched tab.

[image: Rollei QBM]