# What type of mount is this Soligor lens?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, old-lenses, minolta, soligor

What is this type of lens mount?

The notch seems to match Minolta MD, but doesn't quite fit the adapter, also the notch is on the bottom side of the lens (should be on top where the numbers are). There is a push pin near the notch and a aperture index tab which Minolta doesn't seem to have

Lens is a Soligor Zoom Macro 28-80mm C/D F3.5-4.5 MC
[image: Mount of unknown Soligor lens]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I identify the lens mount used for an old Soligor lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60447/how-do-i-identify-the-lens-mount-used-for-an-old-soligor-lens) You should search before opening a new question.

Comment: Edit, saw https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60447/how-do-i-identify-the-lens-mount-used-for-an-old-soligor-lens but my lens doesn't fit minolta-sony adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Rollei QBM (Quick Bayonet Mount) mount first introduced in 1970. This bayonet mount was used on all Rollei's 35mm SLRs, and on most of the Voigtländer VSL models.

It is possible to buy a Rollei QBM adapter to fit most popular cameras.

See also [What is this mount with notched tab on a Soligor Lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119995/what-is-this-mount-with-notched-tab-on-a-soligor-lens)

Photo from [Rollei QBM Adapter guide](https://vintage-camera-lenses.com/rollei-qbm-adapter-guide/)
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Off to order an adapter and try it out